# Scroll to row in UITable that has dynamically sized cells

Tags: uitableview, uiwebview

I am moving from one ViewController to another and I would like to scroll to a specific row in the destination ViewController.

The destination ViewController has cells that contain a WebView each. Each WebView has a different height after it has loaded the HTML content.

When I arrive at the destination ViewController and I use scrollToRowAtIndexPath the table is not jumping to the specific row.

I am presumimg it is because the row height has changed. How do I have the destination ViewController fully load all the WebViews and resize the cells (inherently resizing the UITableView) before calling scrollToRowAtIndexPath?

Let me know if you need more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` in ViewDidAppear method.

This might be because webView is still in process of loading data.